# MAX JSON Char Long

Tags: php, android, json

What is the max char in json parsing, and how to display large text like 800 char?

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "desc": null
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "desc": null
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "desc": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I have problem when my database has 900 char the "JSON" showed null.

Comment: JSON doesn't not impose a length constraint. How do you get get `null` result?

Comment: i dunno why,but if i put a text above 100 character then it show NULL

Comment: put _where_? Also: _it_ ? what is _it_?

Comment: pun in database. that json parsing.

Comment: What database? (technology) what query etc. What JSON parser? JavaScript? PHP? And please think ahead 2 steps before you give an answer that will just get you more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the data you are trying to represent as JSON has some illegal characters in it.  After running it through `json_decode` it is returning null, indicating that the argument provided to it is not valid JSON. @Frits van Campen is correct, though, you really do need to provide more information in order to troubleshoot this issue for you.

Check out [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to determine what your specific issue is related to.  It returns an integer, so you will need to `switch` it against the available constants (as it shows in the manual page example), or you can also use [`json_last_error_msg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) if you just want the message itself.

Comment: what char allowed and not allowed?

Comment: Could be many things.. invalid UTF-8 sequences will break `json_decode` off the top of my head.  Try using `json_last_error` determine if/what the error is

Comment: Thank You, i got it. because illegal CHar